# Regex partial match

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a way to see if a string can be extended with a few characters to match some given regular expression? Can I do it using Regex class? I've googled it for a while and it seems like I should write my own regex parser...

Like Alex said: If the pattern is `abc` the string `ab` would match my criteria and the string `def` or `bc` wouldn't. And I want this to work for any regular expression which is unknown at compile time.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I think whats requested is to see what characters are needed to get a match. eg. "abc" is the pattern, "ab" is provided. The result of said function is "c". However, the pattern must be very explicit to make something like that even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are compiled into decision trees that allow for deciding a match for input of length n in O(n) time. Your custom RE parser could simply count the number of decisions until failure, which when compared with the number of steps necessary for a match, would indicate the "closeness" of the argument to the RE. Assuming you're using fairly simple RE's, and by "extended" mean adding characters to the end of the string, this would be computationally feasible.

Comment: But how do you get access to the decision tree? I wasn't aware you could do that.

Comment: If we could get this information from, for example, C#'s Match object, this would be a much easier problem. I'm assuming that creating a custom parser involves generating your own decision tree / DFA. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times for more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to write your own Regex parser. It would need to be able to take an arbitrary Regex and decompose it into elements. For example, it would need to take `/abc/` and return `{ /abc/, /ab/, /a/ }` and check to see if the input matched any of them.

While this might not be too bad for simple expressions like `/abc/`, it will become onerous for more complicated expressions like `(?<=s)t` that do lookbehind.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, for really simple regular expressions this approach would be good enough